# Invert the Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'm writing the expression extensions method which must inverse the `bool`-typed lambda expression.

Here is what I am doing:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Inverse<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> e)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(e));
}
```

But this raises an exception, that `unary operator is NOT not defined for the type Func<int,bool>`.
I also tried this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Inverse<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> e)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(e.Body));
}
```

But getting this: `Incorrent number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fortunately, this is solved this way:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Inverse<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> e)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(e.Body), e.Parameters[0]);
}
```

Which indicates that `.Lambda<>` method needs a parameter, which we need to pass it from source expression.

Comment: If there isn't any parameters, you should be able to pass `null` I think? Like when you do `Method.Invoke`, just curious if that is the case.

Comment: e.Parameters[0] will throw exception, if no parameters defined.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan there is no way to specify no parameters since the generic type of this extension is `Func<T, bool>`, where `T` is the parameter. Passing null will result the extracting that null, not raising the `IndexOutOfBounds` or any other exception.